# Debian - invoke external script from exim on receipt of emails

Tags: email, debian, external-process, exim

I am looking fopointers on the best approach to process incoming emails to a certain vhost and to call an external script with the email data as parameters - basically to allow email to be sent to a certain "private" email address at a host which then auto inserts something into that sites database. I currently have exim set up as the mail handler.

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow exim single file configurations structure. In routers section write your own custom router that will deliver email to your desired php script. In transport section write your own custom transport that will ensure delivery to the desired script using curl. Just write the following configurations in your `/etc/exim.cnf` file:

```
############ROUTERS
runscript:
        driver = accept
        transport = run_script
        unseen
        no_expn
        no_verify
############TRANSPORT
run_script:
     debug_print = "T: run_script for $local_part@$domain"
     driver = pipe
     command = /home/bin/curl http://my.domain.com/mailTest.php --data-urlencode $original_local_part@$original_domain
```

Where mailTest.php will be your destined script.

Comment: PHP in general and diverting via `curl` in particular seems less than ideal for this task.

Comment: In my case I have to deliver email to multiple destinations. I had to use both drivers i.e accept and redirect. I found only one way to use both and get my work done effectively which I already have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Procmail is a good generic answer.  If your needs are very specific, you could hook in your own script directly from your `.forward` (or Exim's corresponding construct -- can't remember exactly how it differs), but oftentimes, wrapping your own script inside a simple `.procmailrc` helps you avoid a bunch of iffy details of email delivery, and concentrate on the actual processing.

```
:0
' ^Subject: secretpassword adduser \/[A-Z]+
| echo "insert $MATCH into users" | mysql -d users
```